# hasMany association in Ember js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

**app/models/card.js**

```
export default Model.extend({
  title: attr('string'),
  description: attr('string'),
  users: hasMany('user')
});
```

**app/models/user.js**

```
export default Model.extend({
  email: attr('string'),
  name: attr('string')
});
```

**app/routes/card/new.js**

```
actions: {
  save(title, description) {
    const newCard = this.get('store').createRecord('card', {
      title,
      description
    });

    this.get('store').findRecord('user', 1).then(function(user) {
      newCard.set('users', user);
      console.log(newCard);
    });

    newCard.save().then((card) => {
      // go to the new item's route after creating it.
      this.transitionTo('card.card', card);
    });
  }
}
```

So, when I'm saving a `card`, it is throwing me this error:

`Assertion Failed: You must pass an array of records to set a hasMany relationship`.

I want to create an association between the newly created `card` and the `user`.

**Other info:**

Repo link: https://github.com/ghoshnirmalya/hub-client

Ember             : 2.6.1

Ember Data        : 2.6.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You defined that a card has many users:

```
users: hasMany('user')
```

So you can's set 'users' to a single user:

```
newCard.set('users', user);
```

---

So you could either change the `hasMany` to a `belongsTo`, or set the 'users' instead to just one `user` to an array of users: `[user]`

Comment: doing this, just send this response `{"data":{"attributes":{"title":"sad","description":"asdasd"},"relationships":{"users":{"data":[]}},"type":"cards"}}` where the `users.data` is a blank array. 

My backend expects the `users.data` to be something like `[1, 2, 3]` or even `[1]`.

Comment: As `findRecord()` is async your `newCard.save()` might fire before you set the relationship. Try moving the save inside the promise.